# ディクショナリーから要素を取り出すときに型を指定したい

Tags: python, vscode

下記のようなコードを書くと、b が Unknown になってしまいました。

```
h = {
    'bar1': 'baz',
    'bar2': 2,
}

b = h.get('bar1', '')
```

Unknownの様子
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- おそらくPylanceが型を自動判定しているのだと推測しています（Popupに誰が判定しているのか出てないのであくまで推測です）
- getの第2引数であるデフォルト値に `''` 空文字を指定したので str と判定してくれるかと思ったのですが駄目でした

VSCodeで取り出すときに型を認識させる方法はありますか？

---

ちなみに

```
b: str = h.get('bar1', '')
```

は `Unknown | str` でした。

`Unknown | str` の様子
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: もしかしたら、[PEP 561 – Distributing and Packaging Type Information](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/) や [PEP 561 に準拠した型ヒントを含むパッケージの作り方](https://blog.ymyzk.com/2018/09/creating-packages-using-pep-561/) に従って(or参考にして)型ヒント情報を自分で作るとか、あるいは既に有るかもしれないのでPyPIで探すとかすると出来るのかもしれませんね。[types-????](https://pypi.org/search/?q=types-&o=) とか [????-stubs](https://pypi.org/search/?q=-stubs&o=) とか名前の付いたパッケージがそれらしい感じです。

Answer (score 3):

もうちょっと前提がある気がしますが、質問に書いてあることだけで考えると、[typing.TypedDict](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) を使うのが適当かと思います。

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Bar(TypedDict):
    bar1: str
    bar2: int

h: Bar = {
    'bar1': 'baz',
    'bar2': 2,
}

b = h.get('bar1', '')
```

---

単純には

```py
h: Bar = h
```

としてしまう。で、ほかに

```py
h = {
    'bar1': 'baz',
    'bar2': 2,
}
assert isinstance(b, str)
l = len(b)  # strであると保証される
```

としてstrでなかった時に即時エラーにして type narrowing する

```py
h = {
    'bar1': 'baz',
    'bar2': 2,
}
if isinstance(b, str):
    l = len(b)  # strであると保証される
else:
    s = b.bit_length()  # intであると保証される
```

としてisinstanceで type narrowing する

```py
from typing import TypeGuard, Any

def is_bar(val: dict[Any, Any]) -> TypeGuard[Bar]:
    if 'bar1' not in val:
        return False
    if 'bar2' not in val:
        return False
    if not isinstance(val['bar1'], str):
        return False
    if not isinstance(val['bar2'], int):
        return False
    return True

assert is_bar(h)
b = h['bar1']  # Barであると保証される
l = len(b)  # strであると保証される
```

[TypeGurde](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard) の関数を書いて辞書が期待通りの型であることを保証する

などになります。

Comment: upvoteしました。この回答自体は貴重ですが、「もうちょっと前提がある気がしますが」とおっしゃられている通り、オープンソースなどで、ディクショナリーの定義側はいじれないこと（ディクショナリーの生成時には型を指定できない）を想定しています。つまり、タイトルに記載したとおり "要素を取り出すとき" に指定したいです。

Comment: 率直には「strである保証がない（からできるはずがない）」なので、いま何に困っているのか? が知りたいです（いわゆるXY問題です https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/#answer-2702 ）